# Modify list on Observable

Tags: java, jersey, rx-java

I have a `List<JSONObject>` that I create an Observable from to fetch an image URL via a third party API:

```
Observable.from(list)
    .map(jsonObject -> (String) jsonObject.get("url"))
    .flatMap(url -> buildObservable(url))
    .subscribe(async::resume, async::resume);
```

I need to modify the original list to add the retrieved image url to the corresponding JSONObject.  Such that original JSON object:

```
{
     "id": "123456",
     "url": "/img/kitten",
     "desc": "Lorem ipsum..."
}
```

Is now modified to:

```
{
     "id": "123456",
     "image": "http://thirdpartyimagehost.com/v123/unique_image_id"
     "desc": "Lorem ipsum..."
}
```

Upon completion of the third party API call to retrieve the image URL.  How can I map the original List items to the responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 2-parameter version of flatMap:

```
Observable.from(list)
    .flatMap(jsonObject -> buildObservable((String) jsonObject.get("url")),
       (jsonObject, result) -> combine(jsonObject, result)
    )
    .subscribe(async::resume, async::resume);
```

Comment: works!  guess I have a tendency to overcomplicate streams and rx.  :)